# How word2vec deal with the end of a sentence

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

When training, what will word2vec do to cope with the words at the end of a sentence . Will it use the exact words at the beginning of another sentence as the context words of the center words which is 
at the end of last sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The `window` is trimmed to the edges of the current text example. So, the first word of a text only gets its context words from subsequent words in the same text. (No words are retained from previous examples.) Similarly, the last word in a text only gets its context words from previous words in the same text. (No words are pulled in from the next text example.) Each text example (aka `sentence`) stands alone.